# Using the "i-=smallest" statement in the code below, I intend to alter my original array arr, but that isn't happening. What do I do?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Here's the code:

```
n = int(input())
arr = input().split()
arr = [int(x) for x in arr]
smallest = 1001
while(True):
    if smallest==0:
        break
    arr.sort()
    count = 0
    smallest = arr[0]
    for i in arr:
        if i==0:
            arr.remove(i)
        i-=smallest           #This statement.
        count+=1
    print(count)
```

For input:
(n=)6 and
(arr=)5 4 4 2 2 8
The output I'm getting is:
    6
    6
    6...
However, according to me, if my logic works (and the aforementioned statement actually edits my original array elements), the output should turn out to be
    6
    4
    2
    1
instead.

I might have got whole of the thing wrong. I'm an amateur. Any sort of help is appreciated.

Comment: Give more detail how your logic should work. With the (wrong) code, we can't see your thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the inside loop

```
for i in arr:
    if i==0:
        arr.remove(i)
    i-=smallest
    count+=1
```

It assigns the first value in `arr` to `i`. Since no value of the array is zero, it doesn't remove anything from the list.

It then reassigns the value of i by subtracting the smallest value. For the first time through the loop it assigns the value of zero to i. Then it increments count. The list `arr` is unchanged. The line `i=-smallest` has no effect since `i` is reassigned to the next value of the list.

So, with the values 5 4 4 2 8 8 (none of which are zero) that loop is equivalent to

```
for i in arr:
    count+=1
```

Which is why it always prints 6.  I'm not sure why you think it should print 6 4 2 1. I suspect you think the list is being changed, but that the line `if i==0` is always false.

Changing the object being iterated over in a for loop is guaranteed to confuse you. There is almost certainly a better way to achieve what you want. See for example [Remove items from a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python)

Comment: @Jeon
I want my array values to change with the "i-=smallest" statement. How do I achieve that?

Comment: In short don't. Build a new list with a comprehension. see the linked answer.

Comment: Just looking at that. Thank you! The (linked) answer is a bit hard to comprehend for me (novice level), though.